# Decompile .framework bundle with otool?

Tags: macos, frameworks, bundle, otool

I'm trying to decompile a .framework bundle on mac using command line and otool. It doesn't let me - invalid file error or something like that. I see that otool does work with .a static libraries.

Is there any way I can decompile .framework bundles?

Answer (score 1):

framework is a bundle. just open it (say "cd framework_name" in terminal). for example CoreData framework contains binary file CoreData. use otool with -vt options for this binary file and You will see a lot of code on the screen )))) to extract object files from library use lipo tool. Don't forget to use -thin option for lipo ;)
P.S. You can use MachOView GUI tool instead of otool